# How can I remove the close buttons from editor tabs in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans

Variant three in [this specification](http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/closeButton/CloseButtonVersions.html) is what I want, but I see no info on how to enable it or whether it's something that's even been implemented.

Is there a plugin or secret setting that will let me remove the close buttons on tabs. I always use middle click or the keyboard - the close buttons take up a lot of space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is not exactly variant 3, but here is the way how to hide the close buttons completely - run netbeans with switch -J-Dnb.tabs.suppressCloseButton=true, so for example

[NetbeansDirectory]/bin/netbeans -J-Dnb.tabs.suppressCloseButton=true

Hope that helps...

EDIT: It works for NB 6.7.1 and probably for some previous releases. Former switch was -J-Dnetbeans.tab.close.button.enabled=false

EDIT2: I filled a [request for enhancement](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=178474) after reading the comment

Comment: This does what I asked, but a word of warning: This switch (as of 6.7.1) also disables the middle-click-on-tab to close shortcut. I don't know if I'll stick with it because of that, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ouch, this is unpleasant. I mean the middle-mouse button thing. But I guess the tabs close buttons will be more customizable soon, a lot of users complain about the current state. The switch should be just a temporary solution. Anyway, thanks for the rating, it is my first reputation increase :)